# How to apply regex in javascript to obtain single quote from json

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

sample:

```
"{ ' foo ' : ' bar ' baz ' bob ' , 'foo2':'Barr ' s' }"
```

I want single quotes to be filtered, so that i can escape `'` with `\'` and process.

Comment: How did you even get that string? That's where the issue lies. No possible way to generate that in my opinion.

Comment: Even if you do that you don't have valid JSON. So what's the point? Rather fix the code that generates this.

Comment: Why are you re-editing this to this unreadable version? I bet that's why you got downvoted!

Comment: for example if person height was 5'2 inches received from server end without escaping how can i possibly escape this thing in client

Comment: Can you provide more context! Where did you get this string? Did you generate it yourself?

Comment: i am trying  to put in readable way since i have started now only asking questions..

Comment: {'tplid' : 'NONCONTROLITEM','item':'FPSCNC ','itemdesc':'1 1/4' COMP COUPLER BLK / S105036000RU','FrmWH':'WHFMFG1','FrmZnBn':'## | ##','AvlQtyDesc':'Avbl. Qty.','AvlQty':'1.00','AvlUOM':'NO','stksts':'REJECTED'}     this is response i am getting from server  can u see 1/4' which has single quote so i am trying to apply regex and escape that single quote so that i can process

Comment: This problem need to be fixed on server-side where the string get generated!

Comment: you are right since we have no access to server we are trying to do escape value in client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple str.replace() on that string to escape as follows:

```
"{ ' foo ' : ' bar ' baz ' bob ' , 'foo2':'Barr ' s' }".replace("'", "\'");
```

However, as other have stated, your json string is formatted wrong and the solution won't overall because it's only the nested single quote in 'Barr ' s' value that you want to escape. Note: regex won't be able to solve this because it can't match open closing grammar rules or the inverse.